# Dynamically refer to a named range within a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a few names ranges within my spreadsheet:

- range1
- range2
- range3

The formula below works:

```
=Rank(a1,range1)
```

When I evaluate the formula it resolves to be this:

[image]

What this tells me is that the formula resolves the named range to the range and therefore is able to perform the rank.

What I would like to be able to do is have the user select their desired range from a drop down box, in this instance I did the following:

```
=Rank(a1,INDIRECT(f3))
```

(Where f3 is the selected named range on the sheet)

Now, when I evaluate this I end up with the following:

[image]

So this suggests that the formula is just recognising the named range reference as text instead of what it is meant to be in the previous formula.

My question is, how can I get the named range to come through dynamically as expected? How do I stop Excel from reading it as text?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Note that `range2 <> "range2"`. Perhaps you have some extra double quotes.

Comment: For me, it works perfect as you have it.

Comment: The formula evaluates perfectly. Check if the name of the range is same in dropdown and name-manager

Comment: I believe all commentators so far have missed that range1 is not a single, contiguous range, but rather a union of two discontiguous ranges ($J$6:$J$13,$J$19:$J$25). And, unfortunately, such ranges cannot be passed to iNDIRECT.

Comment: @XORLX Good observation -- I certainly missed that. But still -- it doesn't explain why Excel would convert it to text rather than raising a `#REF!` error.

Comment: @JohnColeman It doesn't convert it to text. It does give a #REF! error.

Comment: @XORLX It was to do with the discontiguous range. My solution was to create a second sheet with the rank range in and reference from there. Would you post as an answer?

Comment: @AEJBUG Sure. Have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first few comments to this question appear to have missed that *range1* is not a single, contiguous range, but rather a union of two discontiguous ranges (`$J$6:$J$13,$J$19:$J$25`). And, unfortunately, such ranges cannot be passed to `INDIRECT`.

Regards